# Can't change fonts in TextField in NativeScript

Tags: html, css, angular, nativescript

I just started with NativeScript/Angular and I am not the best with html and css and would like to style the **hint** font in the TextFields. like changing the color, font-size, ... I am not sure why it does not work in the "input-field" class. I would be very thankful, if you someone could answer soon, thank you:)

```css
.form {
    background-color: #6F9DE1;
    margin-top: 2.3%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.header {
    font-size: 25;
    text-align: center;
    color: #111;
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 60;
}

.fields {
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-left: 30;
    margin-right: 30;
}

.input-field {
    height: 45;
    margin-bottom: 20;
    background-color: #4587AD;
    border-radius: 100px;
    /* color: #fff;                would like to change the color here */
}

.input {
    font-size: 20;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary {
    height: 40;
    background-color: #6F9DE1;
    font-size: 20;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.btn-secondary {
    height: 40;
    color: #4587AD;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="form">
    <Label class="header" text="Find 2 Do"></Label>
    </StackLayout> 
        <StackLayout class="fields">
            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField class="input" hint="Full Name"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField class="input" hint="Email"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField class="input" secure="true" hint="Password"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField class="input" secure="true" hint="Confirm Password"></TextField>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout class="btns">
    <Button 
        text="Continue" 
        class="btn btn-primary"
        nsRouterLink="/fullregister" 
    ></Button>

    <Button 
        text="Have an account? Log in" 
        class="btn btn-secondary"
        nsRouterLink="/login" 
    ></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not an expert in CSS myself but I had a similar problem and found 2 ways to "analyze" it: one thing you could do is to check in the DevTools what is being applied instead of your style. Another one, is to postfix the line you commented with !important. If you do it, and the style you want finally applies, then it means that some other style is having higher prio than yours. Watch out though, using 'important!' is usually not the best choice (but sometimes it's ok, see this link: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Could not find the solution by now and !important does not work either. But thanks for the help

Comment: your TextField class is input you need to change there for font-size and color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. You can use style.placeholderColor for changing the color, for example: style.placeholderColor="white" in the TextField tag

```
<StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextField style.placeholderColor="white" class="input" hint="Email" 
                 keyboardType="email"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **`TextField`** class is **`.input`**.

```
<TextField class="input" secure="true" hint="Confirm Password"></TextField>
```

so, you need to change in the **`.input`** class.

```
.input {
    font-size: 20; //change Here
    color: #fff; //change Here
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

**Hope this helps :)**